# grep one line before the match plus the match

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

```
zzzzzzzzz
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb &
ccccccccc &
ddddddddd
hhhhhhhhh
eeeeeeeee
fffffffff &
ggggggggg &
```

in the above line, what i want is to `grep`/`sed`/`awk` (any method is fine) line that have `&` sign plus one line on top of them. so for example the desired output will look like :

```
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb &
ccccccccc &
eeeeeeeee
fffffffff &
ggggggggg &
```

following is what i have tried with no luck.

```
egrep "&" | -b 1 file.txt
```

Answer (score 20):

You can do:

```
grep -B 1 '&$' your_file
```

This will look for lines ending in `&`, remove `$` to match lines with `&` anywhere in them.

The `-B` switch tells `grep` to output "context" lines that come before the lines that match. In this case, since you want one line of context, you need `-B 1`.

This switch is available in GNU `grep` but is not in the POSIX standard, though.

Here's a simple `sed` solution that should help in case you don't have GNU `grep`:

```
sed -n '/&/!N;/&/p' your_file
```

**How it works**

- The `-n` switch suppresses the default "print" action of `sed`
- `/&/!N` means: if the current line doesn't contain `&`, append the next line to the pattern space.
- `/&/p` means: match `&` and print the pattern space.

Comment: @RanaKhan Welcome to Stack Exchange :) I'm glad I could help. Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted (use the tick mark below the vote buttons next to the answer) if it helped solve your problem so that others browsing the site know that this problem is solved.

Comment: +1 for the variant when `GNU/grep` is not available, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to emulate `grep -B1` with `sed`:

```
sed '$!N;/pattern/P;D' infile
```

It's very similar to the [one here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216550). Just like the other one, it reads in the `N`ext line but this time, it `P`rints up to first `\n`ewline *if* the pattern space *matches*,  and then, just like the other one, `D`eletes up to first `\n`ewline and restarts the cycle. So with your sample input:

```
sed '$!N;/&/P;D' infile
```

outputs:

```
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb &
ccccccccc &
eeeeeeeee
fffffffff &
ggggggggg &
```

---

Again, to see how it works, add `l` before and after the `N` to look at the pattern space::

```
sed 'l;$!N;l;/&/P;D' infile
```

e.g. with a sample file:

```
zzzz &
aaaa
bbbb
cccc &
dddd &
hhhh
eeee
ffff &
gggg &
```

these are the commands that `sed` executes and corresponding output:

```
cmd        output            cmd
```

```
l       zzzz &$               N # read in the next line
l       zzzz &\naaaa$         # pattern space matches so print up to \n
P       zzzz &                D # delete up to \n 
l       aaaa$                 N # read in the next line
l       aaaa\nbbbb$           D # delete up to \n (no match so no P)
l       bbbb$                 N # read in the next line
l       bbbb\ncccc &$         # pattern space matches so print up to \n
P       bbbb                  D # delete up to \n
l       cccc &$               N # read in the next line
l       cccc &\ndddd &$       # pattern space matches so print up to \n
P       cccc &                D # delete up to \n
l       dddd &$               N # read in the next line
l       dddd &\nhhhh$         # pattern space matches so print up to \n
P       dddd &                D # delete up to \n
l       hhhh$                 N # read in the next line
l       hhhh\neeee$           D # delete up to \n (no match so no P)
l       eeee$                 N # read in the next line
l       eeee\nffff &$         # pattern space matches so print up to \n
P       eeee                  D # delete up to \n
l       ffff &$               N # read in the next line
l       ffff &\ngggg &$       # pattern space matches so print up to \n
P       ffff &                D # delete up to \n
l       gggg &$               # last line so no N 
l       gggg &$               # pattern space matches so print up to \n
P       gggg &                D # delete up to \n
```